# Does it make sense to do PCA when you got two variables with the same scale?

Tags: pca, unsupervised-learning

I want to make to measure perceived standard of living in different countries in Europe. I got two variables from the European Social Survey that almost covers this:

- slvpen: Standard of living of pensioners: 0 = Extremely bad, 10 = Extremely good.
- slvuemp: Standard of living of unemployed: 0 = Extremely bad, 10 = Extremely good.

I want to combine these variables into one variable in order to get the best indicator of standard of living generally. As far as I see, I have two options:

1. Additive scale: `1/2 * slvpen + 1/2 * slvuemp`
2. PCA-analysis:

I am a bit confused whether I need to do PCA or not as the scales of the two variables are equal. However, their standard deviations do differ a bit:

**slvpens:**

`Min.   1st Qu. Median    Mean  3rd Qu.    Max.    Standard Deviation 
 0.000   3.000   5.000   4.587   6.000   10.000               2.28857`

**slvuemp:**

`Min.   1st Qu.  Median   Mean  3rd Qu.    Max.    Standard Deviation 
 0.000   3.000   4.000   4.095   5.000   10.000              2.099822`

What would be the smartest thing to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, before doing PCA, features are standardized so that they're at similar scales (actually same variance) because the first principal components will try to capture as much variance as possible and if some dimension has a large variance, the first PC will be dominated by it not because it explains the data very well but because the variance is abruptly high. So, having the same scales is not a problem at all.

The utility of PCA is having other axes (PCs) that are linear combinations of your original features. This means you'll get two new axes in the form:

```
pc1 = a * slvpen + b * slvunemp
pc2 = c * slvpen + d * slvunemp
```

pc1, (the first principal component), will exploit all the correlation between the original axes and show you a direction that the data varies a lot. Since the data is 2D, I strongly suggest you to plot your data and principal components to make the most sense out of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I have been looking a bit more into but a few things still doesn't make sense to me: 

**1)** Regarding standardization: Wouldn't you only standardize if the scales are different? Does it make sense to standardize in this case as the scales are alike? 

**2)** I find that one of the biggest strengths with PCA is that it enables you to combine variables with different scales in a meaningful way. However, what is the strength in this case? Is it that it, in theory, should weight the variable with the higest standard deviation?

Comment: @KaKaDK95 1) having the same scale doesn't guarantee the same variance. Standardising ensures equal variances. In your case, variances are small, so the effect of the operation will be less visible, but it doesn't hurt to do. 2) PCA enables [linearly] combining features and obtaining new ones that try to capture more of the data variance with lesser number of axes. This is done by exploiting the *covariances* between the features. The essence of PCA doesn't lie in finding meaningful coefficients for variables with different scales (except the cases where you really want to aim the variance).